# Chrome blocks iframe with same origin even with --disable-web-security

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I am on a page with the following domain
`https://my.example.com`

When I type the following in the chrome console:
`document.querySelector('.my-app-iframe').contentDocument` I get `null` because the iframe `src` is `https://members.example.com`

Launching chrome (Using nightwatch.js test runner) with the `--disable-web-security` flag solves this. I can now access the `contentDocument` of the iframe and interact with contents.

But then this happens:

`document.querySelector('.my-app-iframe')` : 
`<iframe src='https://members.example.com'> //all good`

`var myFrame = document.querySelector('.my-app-iframe').contentDocument.querySelector('#iframe1')` : 
`<iframe id='myContent' src='/Content/myApp.aspx'>`

`myFrame.contentDocument.querySelector('#iframe2')` 
`<iframe src='https://my.example.com/index.html'>`

Now I want to access one last nested Iframe  but I get this:

`myFrame.contentDocument.querySelector('#iframe2').contentDocument.querySelector('#iframe3')`

`Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://my.example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

This is weird because I'm starting from a website that's at `my.example.com`, and since I've disabled web security I can access an iframe with a different origin. But then I'm unable to access another nested iframe with the same domain that im starting from. Why is this happening and what could be a solution?

Comment: I agree that it's odd that `--disable-web-security` isn't covering your situation. Regardless, it may be that only the context inside `#iframe2`, as the immediate ancestor, can access `#iframe3`'s context. If that's the case, you'd need to inject code into `#iframe2` and execute it in the context of `#iframe2` to access the content of `#iframe3`.